# apache-commons DescriptiveStatistics gives wrong StandardDeviation?

Tags: java, statistics, apache-commons

I have this code:

```
    DescriptiveStatistics stats = new DescriptiveStatistics( new double[] {2,4,4,4,5,5,7,9} );
    System.out.println("var="+stats.getVariance());
    System.out.println("sd="+stats.getStandardDeviation());
```

I took the example from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation. The answer should be var=4.0, sd=2.0, but what I get is:

```
    4.571428571428571
    2.138089935299395
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getVariance()` divides by `n-1`, here from the [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/descriptive/DescriptiveStatistics.html#getVariance--):

> Returns the (sample) variance of the available values.
>
> This method returns the bias-corrected sample variance (using `n - 1` in the denominator). Use `getPopulationVariance()` for the non-bias-corrected population variance.

Background: typically, one has a sample from the population, and by calculating the bias-corrected (or unbiased) sample variance, the expected value of the calculated estimate equals the population variance.  I wrote sample code that demonstrates this for this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39195083/1628638).  And Wikipedia has background on [population variance vs. sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance).