# What is the difference between numpy var() and statistics variance() in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying one Dataquest exercise and I figured out that the variance I am getting is different for the two packages.

e.g for `[1,2,3,4]`

```
from statistics import variance
import numpy as np
print(np.var([1,2,3,4]))
print(variance([1,2,3,4]))
//1.25
//1.6666666666666667
```

The expected answer of the exercise is calculated with `np.var()`

**Edit**
I guess it has to do that the later one is sample variance and not variance. Anyone could explain the difference?

Comment: cross-site dupe  http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17890

Comment: try help(np.var)  which will show you the options available for sample and population statistics ... np.var([1,2,3,4], ddof=0) =>1.25 ... and  np.var([1,2,3,4], ddof=1) => 1.6666666666666667

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use this

```
print(np.var([1,2,3,4],ddof=1))

1.66666666667
```

*Delta Degrees of Freedom*: the divisor used in the calculation is `N - ddof`, where N represents the number of elements. By default, `ddof` is zero.

The mean is normally calculated as `x.sum() / N`, where `N = len(x)`. If, however, `ddof` is specified, the divisor `N - ddof` is used instead.

In standard statistical practice, `ddof=1` provides an unbiased estimator of the variance of a hypothetical infinite population. `ddof=0` provides a maximum likelihood estimate of the variance for normally distributed variables.

Statistical libraries like numpy use the variance *n* for what they call var or variance and the standard deviation

For more information refer this documentation : [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.var.html)

Comment: The last bit is incorrect. numpy uses `ddof=0` for both `var()` and `std()` by default. Other libraries choose `ddof=1` by default for both. I know of no library that uses one convention for variance and another for standard deviation.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that dividing by N-1 gives an unbiased estimate for the mean, which can give the impression that dividing by N-1 is therefore slightly more accurate, albeit a little more complex. What is too often not stated is that dividing by N gives the minimum variance estimate for the mean, which is likely to be closer to the true mean than the unbiased estimate, as well as being somewhat simpler.

Comment: source please.

I have been looking at examples of the unbiased sample variance being much more accurate over a large sample size.

Comment: What do you mean "dividing by N-1 gives an unbiased estimate for the mean"? The mean of the samples is obviously an unbiased estimate of the mean, so dividing the sum of samples by N-1 gives us a biased estimate for the mean.