# Create "leakage-free" Variables in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with several thousand observations and I would like to create "leakage-free" variables in Python. So I am looking for a way to calculate e.g. a group-specific mean of a variable without the single observation in row i.
For example:

```
| Group | Price | leakage-free Group Mean |  
-------------------------------------------
|   1   |  20   |           25            |
|   1   |  40   |           15            |
|   1   |  10   |           30            |
|   2   |  ...  |           ...           |
```

I would like to do that with several variables and I would like to create mean, median and variance in such a way, so a computationally fast method might be good. If a group has only one row I would like to enter 0s in the leakage-free Variable.
As I am rather a beginner in Python, some piece of code might be very helpful. Thank You!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With one-liner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1,1,1,2], 'Price':[20,40,10,30]})

df['lfgm'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: (x.sum()-x)/(len(x)-1)).fillna(0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Group  Price  lfgm
0      1     20  25.0
1      1     40  15.0
2      1     10  30.0
3      2     30   0.0
```

**Update:**

For median and variance (not one-liners unfortunately):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': [1,1,1,1,2], 'Price':[20,100,10,70,30]})

def f(x):
    for i in x.index:
        z = x.loc[x.index!=i, 'Price']
        x.at[i, 'mean'] = z.mean()
        x.at[i, 'median'] = z.median()
        x.at[i, 'var'] = z.var()
    return x[['mean', 'median', 'var']]

df = df.join(df.groupby('Group').apply(f))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Group  Price       mean  median          var
0      1     20  60.000000    70.0  2100.000000
1      1    100  33.333333    20.0  1033.333333
2      1     10  63.333333    70.0  1633.333333
3      1     70  43.333333    20.0  2433.333333
4      2     30        NaN     NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Great! Is there also such an easy  way to get the median and the variance?

Comment: good one, if possible try and include mean inside the function too. :) so OP directly can apply the func. +1 from me

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, but I think the variance is not correct. When I calculate `np.var([100,10,70])` the result is 1400 and not 2100.

Comment: That's because numpy divides by N by default, not (N-1). This can be changed with `ddof` parameter: `np.var([100,10,70], ddof=1) = 2100`. See for example discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204400/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-var-and-statistics-variance-in-python

Comment: But you can also just change to `x.at[i, 'var'] = np.var(z)` in case you want to use numpy's `var` function

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
grp = df.groupby('Group')
n = grp['Price'].transform('count')
mean = grp['Price'].transform('mean')
df['new_col'] = (mean*n - df['Price'])/(n-1)
print(df)

   Group  Price  new_col
0      1     20     25.0
1      1     40     15.0
2      1     10     30.0
```

Note: This solution will be faster than using apply, you can test using `%%timeit` followed by the codes.

Comment: How can I transfer this to median and variance?