# Effective numpy array calculating in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I need to calculate this special variance estimate (see pic. below). I have feature matrix X - dxl (d - # features, l - # objects). It's simply to do this in for cycles:

```py
    var_list = []

    for i in range(X.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i + 1, X.shape[0]):
            var_list.append(((X[i, :] - X[j, :]) ** 2).sum())

    variance = np.median(var_list)
```

But this is ineffective because of python cycle. Is there a way to do it by numpy faster?

Formula for variance:

[image]

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). As for the rest, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.var()` to find the variance faster. You can see the documentation https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html

Comment: Also note that if you want the empirical (or sample variance) you need to use `np.var(x, ddof=1)`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41204400/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-var-and-statistics-variance-in-python

Comment: But I said, that I need a special variance estimate, which is not implemented in numpy.